# How make fetch requests on API with private ip?

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, docker, kubernetes

I am working on project with microservices, and i have some issues.
I have a ReactJS frontend, and a ASP.NET API, and i am working on docker/kubernetes environment.
I try to fetch data on my front from API like this :

```
    const https = require("https");
    const agent = new https.Agent({
        mode: "cors",
        method: 'GET',
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    })
    return fetch(hostApi1 +'/api/Weather/Index', { agent })
```

hostapi1=https://10.0.96.227:5001
The Frontend have a public ip, and the api a private ip.

But the console return this error :

`FetchWeather.tsx:130 GET https://10.0.96.227:5001/api/Weather/Index net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

But when i try this from the front container :

`curl -k https://10.0.96.227:5001/api/Weather/Index`

I obtain a good response with my data.

So there some specifics to add in my request for fetch data on API with private IP ?
(when i add a public ip for my api it works, but this this not the aim)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is it a client side app?

Comment: yes, i have this error through client browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your ReactJS frontend is running in user's browser. So you need to connect to backend using external IP. You cannot use private cluster ip from outside the cluster.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but if i give a public ip for my API service it can create some security issues... Is there other way to request my api without exposing it ?

Comment: Because I saw on this ressource : https://medium.com/free-code-camp/communication-in-kubernetes-microservices-bf0a2af06551 it request the service directly(with the service name).

Comment: In the example you have shared both the services are server side apps. You have a client side app. You can to to put your api service behind a gateway service which is exposed externally.

Comment: Yes i think it is the best solution, thank you very much for your help !